# Can't run project anymore

Tags: iphone, xcode

My project used to be called "TextFieldDemo", then I renamed it to "ShiftCipher". I cannot launch the project anymore. This is the message I'm getting. Can so please help?

> GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1708) (Mon Aug  8 20:32:45
>   UTC 2011) Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc. GDB is free
>   software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
>   welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain
>   conditions. Type "show copying" to see the conditions. There is
>   absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
>   This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin".sharedlibrary
>   apply-load-rules all Attaching to process 2285. 2011-10-30
>   19:35:49.914 ShiftCipher[2285:f803] *** Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could
>   not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle  (loaded)' with name 'TextFieldDemoViewController''
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x14ce052 0x11b9d0a 0x1476a78 0x14769e9 0x585838 0x42ce2c 0x42d3a9 0x42d5cb 0x38da73 0x38e0b8 0x230b 0x3659d6
>   0x3668a6 0x375743 0x3761f8 0x369aa9 0x1bc4fa9 0x14a21c5 0x1407022
>   0x140590a 0x1404db4 0x1404ccb 0x3662a7 0x367a9b 0x225d 0x21d5)
>   terminate called throwing an exceptionCurrent language:  auto;
>   currently objective-c (gdb)

TextFieldDemoViewController is now called ShiftCipherViewController. I don't know why it's looking for it with the old name.

Comment: When changing names it is best to use the Xcode refactoring tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a nib that use to be named TextFieldDemoViewController.xib. The file was probably renamed to something like ShiftCipherViewController.xib. You are likely still referencing TextFieldDemoViewController in your initWithNibName.

Comment: How do I change the initWithNibName?

Comment: Do a text search in your project for TextFieldDemoViewController

Comment: Could it be some cache in the iPhone simulator?

Comment: It is possible that you are creating the VC inside of a nib, this is often the case for UITabViewController. Child nib names are specified inside of the IB window in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Look in the XIB file that you're attempting to load and see what the "File's Owner" is listed as.

My guess is that it is still set to "TextFieldDemoViewController" instead of "ShiftCipherViewController".  That's where you would need to make your change.

Comment: The refactoring tools will fix this properly in XC4.2

Comment: The File's owner is listed as "TextFieldDemoDelegate". Just need to figure out how to change it

Comment: It's a yellowish orange box in the interface builder of MainWindow.xib. When I hover over it, it's called TextFieldDemoAppDelegate but when I click it, it opens ShiftCipherAppDelegate. Any ideas as to how to change it?

Comment: fixed the app delegate. Unfortunately, the problem still persists.

Comment: do a full clean and rebuild and see if that fixes your problem. Updated xibs sometimes do not always get copied into the build products directories.